# How to get all events from 'All in one Events calender' plugin in JSON format?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-json-api, json

I am using `All in one Events Calendar` plugin to add the events. It works fine in CMS. I would like to display the events data in mobile version. for this i used `JSON-API` for obtaining web-services in json format.

To obtain all events , I dint find any plugin which will full-fill my requirement. so i started writing php code and uploaded the `getevents.php` to `www/.../services/getevents.php`

When i execute the file it is redirected to Calendar page in my cms. But i am expecting a json formatted output of all the events.

Please suggest a solution...
Thanks

Comment: I have edited the question title, yours was pretty sure to get downvotes! ;)

Comment: Thanks, downvotes is not a problem. Solution is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do the same thing. I used the JSON API plugin and had to create a new controller for JSON API that read the specific data out of the tables that All-in-One created.

Unfortunately there really were not the right calls in the calendar plugin to access all the data (or at least on the older version I used this for) so I had to write the whole controller to do it.

It took only a few hours to do and was pretty trivial once you look at the database structure, so this would be my recommended method to do this.

Comment: Thank you Khirok for your suggestion. I would have given an upvote for this , Unfortunately i am not eligible. 
I did the same thing, looking into database and started writing queries to fetch data.

Comment: @Ramarajudantuluri The problem why you can't do this is that you don't _accept_ answers - which you should do once you got a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to import the events from your calendar (to do this click the "Subscribe" button) and then use this converter:

http://ical2json.pb.io/the-website.com/path/to/file.ics

For example you have the link: http://www.mysite.com/events.ics.

To get this data in JSON format use the URL: http://ical2json.pb.io/www.mysite.com/events.ics.

I got this help from the team who created All-In-One calendar events

Hope this will help You